# Ignite slowdown when node increase to 2

Tags: ignite

I use Ignite.Net and run ignite in my .net core app process.
My application receives some messages (5000 per second) and I put or remove some keys according to the messages received. The cache mode is replicated, with default Primary_Sync write mode.
Everything is good and I can process up to 20,000 messages/sec.
But when I run another ignite node on another machine, everything changes. Processing speed is reduced up to 1000 messages per second.
perhaps it's due to that some operations do on the network, but I want just put or remove keys on the local instance and replicate them (changed keys) to other nodes. Write mode is Primary_Sync and this means ignite must put or remove key on the local node (because all nodes are the same due to replicated mode and no need to distribute them on other nodes) and then replicate them to other nodes asynchronously.
Where is the problem? 
Is the slowdown due to network operations?

Comment: Can you please provide the code? Ideally fully working project which I could run and profile.

Comment: I create a repository for the sample project: [link](https://github.com/MasiumDev/IgniteSample.git). **Be sure to read README.md**

Comment: I did not check your reproducer, but for every entry Ignite still has a primary node and backups.
This means 50% of times primary commit will happen on non-local node. Are you sure you are not constrained by trying to do it in a single thread sequentially?

Comment: I may not understand what you mean, but if 50% of entry commits on a non-local node, this can decrease performance. How can I constrain that Ignite commits all entries just on the local node, then replicate them asynchronously? When the cache mode is replicated, why Ignite must commit to a non-local node?

Comment: @alamar I checked your notion, That's right. Now, is there any way to force Ignite to commit all operations on the local node and then replicate them?

Comment: If you can collocate data on per node basis (so node always operates on "its" half of data) then yes.

Comment: @alamar Order is important in the execution. How can I disable distributed operation in ignite?

Comment: You can try using `LOCAL` caches or, better yet, create caches with node filter of node dedicated to that cache. Are you sure you want a distributed DB if you want it to not be distributed??

Comment: I must put or remove 10,000 keys/sec. If it does operate on a remote node through network my throughput decreases. On other side, I want replicate them to other nodes with the replicated cache.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code (could not run it - requires messing with SQL server), I can provide the following recommendations:

1. **Use [DataStreamer](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/data-streamers)**. Always use streamer when adding/removing batches of data.
2. Try using multiple threads to load the data. Ignite APIs are thread-safe.
3. *Maybe* try `CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FullAsync`

Together this should result in a noticeable speedup, no matter how many nodes.

Comment: I prepared sample data in SQL Server for your test, in real I receive data from AMQP broker like RabbitMQ.

Comment: CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FullAsync not safe, when I use this mode, if in the middle of operation I get one of the keys I put, in this mode, the key may not have been set yet. This mode do operations on local node async too.

Comment: Please run and test sample project.

Comment: I changed the code, It no longer depends on SQL server and read data from a binary file.

Comment: @user3657370 have you tried the recommendations above?

Comment: 1 - In real, I receive the messages one by one, for this reason I can't batches of data. 2-Order is important in the execution. 3-FullAsync mode throw an exception if a remote node crashes.